# Permitir ingreso de numero a partir de una posicion especifica en un input Angular

Tags: validación, input

estoy empezando con esta herramienta mu util e interesante y quisiera saber somo puedo restringir el ingreso de numeros solo a partir de cierta posicion es decir primero acepte letras y despues de la tercera letra recien me permita ingresar numero, estoy tratando con el validator del formgroup pero aun no encuentro solución espero puedan apoyarme con algun ejemplo

Comment: Hola, llevas algo hecho?

Comment: <input matInput type="text" *ngIf="nombre.value.length > 2" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" formControlName="nombre" /> pero no me esta funcionando

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega eso

Comment: Puedes intentar validaciones con regex, la que acepta 3 caracteres iniciales en letras y luego numeros es esta **^[a-zA-Z]{3}\d*$** Te recomiendo este sitio https://regex101.com/

Comment: Genial Jonathan RG, gracias, tb me funcionó con: **pattern="^[^0-9 ]{3}.*" required formControlName="nombre"**